# Use different importModuleSpecifier Visual Studio Code for sub packages in monorepo

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I want to use different auto imports in packages in my pnpm workspace, most of the repos are fine with relative but in one I want to use non-relative imports, I have tried creating multiple settings.json but that doesn't seem to work.